# Python, unpacking a .jar file, doesnt work

Tags: python, jar, unzip

So, I'm trying to unzip a `.jar` file using this code:
It won't unzip, only 20 / 500 files, and no folders/pictures
The same thing happens when I enter a `.zip` file in filename.
Any one any suggestions?

```
import zipfile
zfilename = "PhotoVieuwer.jar"
if zipfile.is_zipfile(zfilename):
    print "%s is a valid zip file" % zfilename
else:
    print "%s is not a valid zip file" % zfilename
print '-'*40

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile( zfilename, "r" )

zfile.printdir()
print '-'*40

for info in zfile.infolist():
    fname = info.filename

    data = zfile.read(fname)


    if fname.endswith(".txt"):
        print "These are the contents of %s:" % fname
        print data


    filename = fname
    fout = open(filename, "w")
    fout.write(data)
    fout.close()
    print "New file created --> %s" % filename
    print '-'*40
```

But, it doesn't work, it unzips maybe 10 out of  500 files
Can anyone help me on fixing this?

Already Thanks!

I tried adding, what Python told me, I got this:
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

body is limited to **30000** characters; you entered **153562**
and only the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\uc\TeStINGGFDSqAEZ.py", line 26, in <module>
    fout = open(filename, "w")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'net/minecraft/client/ClientBrandRetriever.class'
```

The files that get unzipped:

```
amw.Class
amx.Class
amz.Class
ana.Class
ane.Class
anf.Class
ang.Class
ank.Class
anm.Class
ann.Class
ano.Class
anq.Class
anr.Class
anx.Class
any.Class
anz.Class
aob.Class
aoc.Class
aod.Class
aoe.Class
```

Comment: A .jar file is not the same as a .zip file. I believe your code would only work for .zip files.

Comment: Everywhere i look, they tell me to use zipfile method, so i've been trying to do that last few hours, but nothing worked ...

Comment: Have you tried using an unzipping program on the failed files, to verify that they are zip files?

Comment: Jar files are basically zip files and usually can be unzipped using any zip compatible archiver - including the zip module of Python

Comment: I know, but it just doesnt work as you can see above...

Comment: @JoppeDnbCuyper Can you see a pattern on the files your code works on or fails? If you can figure out what specific files it fails on, you'll have a small test case. It's difficult to work with a set of 500 files when trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: @JoppeDnbCuyper Also, in the other message you had posted the traceback I think. It would be helpful to have it here too.

Comment: @Levon All the files it does extract, have 3 letters, thats the only thing they have in cummon(if i wrote that right)

Comment: @JoppeDnbCuyper so if the name has 4 letters, it won't work with your program right? what happens if you try to unzip it with some other program as was suggested in a comment above, does that work?

Comment: I added some files to the comment

Comment: Unpack the archive with something like 7zip and verify that it works. Otherwise it may be a custom archive that just happens to use the .jar extension, or is based on the .jar format with custom entries, who knows. Then at least you know your approach is the right one and it's a different issue.

Comment: @JoppeDnbCuyper:  Did you consider my answer?  It should solve the issue.  Since you were still stuck ofter I posted it, I have edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: with winrar it works fine, steven , testing now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This traceback tells you what you need to know:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\uc\TeStINGGFDSqAEZ.py", line 26, in <module>
    fout = open(filename, "w")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'net/minecraft/client/ClientBrandRetriever.class'
```

The error message says that either the file `ClientBrandRetriever.class` doesn't exist or the directory `net/minecraft/client` does not exist.  When a file is opened for writing Python creates it, so it can't be a problem that the file does not exist.  It must be the case that the directory does not exist.

Consider that this works

```
>>> open('temp.txt', 'w') 
<open file 'temp.txt', mode 'w' at 0x015FF0D0>
```

but this doesn't, giving nearly identical traceback to the one you are getting:

```
>>> open('bogus/temp.txt', 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bogus/temp.txt'
```

Creating the directory fixes it:

```
>>> os.makedirs('bogus')
>>> open('bogus/temp.txt', 'w')
<open file 'bogus/temp.txt', mode 'w' at 0x01625D30>
```

Just prior to opening the file you should check if the directory exists and create it if necessary.

So to solve your problem, replace this

```
fout = open(filename, 'w')
```

with this

```
head, tail = os.path.split(filename) # isolate directory name
if not os.path.exists(head):         # see if it exists
    os.makedirs(head)                # if not, create it
fout = open(filename, 'w')
```

Comment: it has to create the folders to yea

Comment: nothing, just : http://i.imgur.com/qiEII.png , so basicly, it's finished, but nothing got unpacked..

Comment: @JoppeDnbCuyper: Your call to `zfile.printdir()` is not printing anything except a header line.  The zip file looks empty.  This would explain whey the loop (`for info in zfile.infolist()`) doesn't print anything.  There doesn't appear to be anything to loop over.  Double check your zipfile.

Answer (score 1):

If `python -mzipfile -e PhotoVieuwer.jar dest` works then you could:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("PhotoVieuwer.jar") as z:
    z.extractall()
```

Comment: @JoppeDnbCuyper: what does nothing the first command (it should extract the archive to `dest` directory) or the script (it extracts all files to current working directory)? If the script doesn't produce an error; it works.

Comment: run `python -V`, `python -mzipfile -t PhotoVieuwer.jar`, and `python -mzipfile -l PhotoVieuwer.jar`. What do you see?

Comment: run using python, or using cmd?

Comment: Using cmd from a directory that has the jar file

Comment: `python -V` is a command that prints python version. If "nothing happens" when you run it then you should fix it e.g., complete [the 0 exercise](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html) from [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/intro.html). Make sure `python -V` works. Then find any other zip archive and run the above `python -mzipfile` commands with it.